# How do I store data in a wrapper class from a method deep in the stack?

Tags: java, wrapper

I have a class (XMLBuilder) that builds an xml doc.  Within this process I parse some data to make it fit in the xml model.  I would like to capture data related to the parsing.  So I have a wrapper class (XMLBuilderWrapper) designed to capture the parsed data.

My question is: how do I access the wrapper class from the parser (or vice versa) so as to store the data?  I don't want to return this data back up through the stack if I can help it.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a wrapper in the usual sense.  A wrapper is an adapter between one API and another.  The wrapped object typically has no knowledge of its wrapper.  Perhaps what you'd really like to do is register callbacks in your XMLBuilder to another class instance which would hold your data.  A common use case for wrappers is to *add instrumentation* to an existing class.  Callback frameworks usually work poorly with adapters because the wrapped object typically doesn't know about its wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using some form of recursion. You can pass the reference of the wrapper as a parameter. You don't have to return anything. Simply instantiate the wrapper before the first call of the builder and pass the reference as a parameter. All changes you make to the wrapper will occur on the same object, no matter how deep you are in the stack.

Also, if I understood you correctly, your wrapper class isn't exactly a wrapper. Its more like a model.